# Proximity sensor strange operation iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, proximitysensor

I am developing an application that requires the proximity sensor constantly active during execution.

I put this code in the app delegate:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`

`[UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;`

The problem is that after a short period of time even though the sensor is covered, the diplay lights up.

I have tried using third-party applications that make use of the sensor and the display remains dark.

Does anyone know how to fix it? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465284/proximity-sensor-disable-my-screen