# Proximity sensor disable my screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I develop one app in that used the the `Proximity Sensor`. Detect properly the state change when move hand around proximity sensor. but display black screen when stop hand in front of proximity sensor. i don't want this black screen.

i tried this line of code.

```
UIApplication *thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
thisApp.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

but not work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Exactly how are you writing code against the proximity sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there's no way to prevent the screen from blacking out when the proximity sensor is covered.  Hopefully Apple will change this in the future.